# How to use onvif services provided by Axis camera

Tags: wsdl, ip-camera, onvif

I'm new to webservices,can someone help with to get started.I have an Axis M3004-V camera and i want to use the services(Webservices) provided by them,m not knowing how to start.I googled for the WSDl file and all i found is this http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl ,how to get the wsdl file?
how do i generate the client code using this WSDL?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably start by reading the ONVIF [application developer's guide](http://www.onvif.org/Portals/0/documents/WhitePapers/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer%27s_Guide.pdf). You could also register to [developer.onvif.org](http://developer.onvif.org/) , where you can talk with other people implementing ONVIF.

Comment: application developers guide is not helping me much its confusing.

Comment: then register to the forum, and ask there for clarification.

Comment: I tried registering on the forum, and was not granted access. So I mailed them as instructed, and they replied that I have to sign a membership in order to get access to the developer forum...Didn't like that to be honest!

Comment: Yes, excuse me, my fault. I thought the ONVIF forum was for anyone, but it is only for onvif members. Check thi question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259336/onvif-trying-to-understand-how-it-works