# Onvif - trying to understand how it works

Tags: c, xml, web-services, soap, onvif

First of all, I have no experience in working with ONVIF at all. I got myself a scholarship at a company and was asked to work with it (to control some cameras and get photos from them), but they don't know how it works either, so no-one can help me much...

I was reading through the specifications available at the ONVIF webpage but I don't really get it. I know I have to use SOAP, C (I was asked to do the app in C), XML and web services. That much I understand but I don't know how am I supposed to use them. I'm not here so that you can do the work for me (that ain't fun) I just would like to know if someone here could guide me a little about what to start learning and in which order. If there's something I forgot to explain I'll add it as soon as I can.

Comment: say something more. Are you working in linux or windows?

Comment: I'm working on linux(i dont know the version i will be using yet right now im with ubuntu 14.04 LTS), i get more or less the idea of WS with SOAP but i have no idea how to implement it, and there are few to none guides for webservices in C

Comment: I had written code for getting a snapshot from an ONVIF compliant IP Camera that you may find useful. The code uses the gsoap toolkit & is well commented, and should be easy to follow. [Here's the link to the github repo](https://github.com/Sufi-Al-Hussaini/onvif-gsoap-by-example). It should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

So, you have to start with [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).

Pelco has a [guide](http://pdn.pelco.com/content/generating-onvif-proxy-classes-using-gsoap-0) to get started with gSOAP, it is for windows but it is valid for Linux as well. As you start learning gSOAP, check the last [FAQ](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapfaq.html) of gSOAP about the namespaces.

Finally, on the ONVIF website there's an [Application Programmers Guide](https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmers_Guide-1.pdf), which is old but still interesting. ONVIF has a [forum](http://developer.onvif.org/) for all people willing to learn the protocol. It does not require you to be member to access it, you can join it for free and check all the questions there.

Comment: THx for the info, however the forum doesn't allow me to registre, it says it is only for member companies. Anyway i will put tto use the info and see if i can manage to probe the cam.

Comment: Ooops, my fault about the forum. I remeber that membership was not requried any more, but I was wrong.

Comment: Btw the guide is for C++, so its of no use to me, it seems like the files i need to generate must be C specific, i'm already working on that though.

Comment: gSOAP can output for C as well as for C++. It's a flag you pass to it. About the ONVIF APG, it may be usefult once you know how to deal with gSOAP because it tells you what the ONVIF protocol expects you to do to interact with the cameras.

Comment: I didnt mean the ONVIF APG Guide, i meant the Pelco one, the APG looks promising once i deal with gSOAP, cause i still have no idea how to how :D

Answer (score 1):

A good approach is to study existing code from open source projects. A few of them can be found from [an ONVIF challenge top 10 list](https://www.onvif.org/blog/blog/2018/07/12/onvif-challenge-announces-top-10/). Also from the [top 7 ONVIF open source projects](https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/onvif). Especially it looks the following ones should be a good starting points:

- An [ONVIF Service Server - onvif_srvd](https://github.com/KoynovStas/onvif_srvd) which runs on a linux machine so that your RTSP cameras will be discoverable by other ONVIF tools or clients.
- An [ONVIF server for PI that turns a webcam into an IP Camera](https://github.com/BreeeZe/rpos).
- An [ONVIF client with GUI built-in](https://gitlab.com/caspermeijn/onvifviewer).